# Cocos2d-js: How to use a custom ttf font on android devices?

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I use following code to display a custom ttf font:

```
ml.score = cc.LabelTTF.create(ml.totalPoints.toString(), "fonts/American Typewriter.ttf", 60);
ml.score.setPosition(ml.size.width/2,BS*0.6);
ml.score.retain();
ml.score.setColor(cc.color(200,160,70));
ml.scoreBar.addChild(ml.score, 5);
```

In Android the font is not displayed. In Chrome / Firefox browsers it is.

I'm using cocos2d-js 30RC.

Wat?

Comment: Are you preloading your font? (along with all your other assets, in your `resource.js` file for example)

Answer (score 3):

I made a mistake. The file name was wrong. It should be

```
ml.score = cc.LabelTTF.create(ml.totalPoints.toString(), "res/fonts/American Typewriter.ttf", 60);
```

Otherwise the code works fine.
(shame ...)

Answer (score 3):

Michael's answer works on my Android, but does not work in my browser.

I could not find a multi-purpose method, but adding this in the head of `index.html` worked for my browser:

```
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lobster';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Lobster'), url(res/Lobster.ttf) format('woff');
}
</style>
```

with this in your js:

```
var titleLabel = new cc.LabelTTF("Hello World", "Lobster", 72);
```

Since this method only works in my browser, and the other method only works on my phone, I might need to come up with a toggle.