# Cocos2d-js: Custom TTF font won't display in Android

Tags: truetype, cocos2d-js

I define the font resources with

```
var res = {
   indieflower_ttf: {type:"font", name:"IndieFlower", srcs:["res/fonts/IndieFlower.ttf"]},
}
```

And create a TTF label with:

```
var text = cc.LabelTTF.create(text, "IndieFlower", bubble.fontsize, cc.size(60,0),cc.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT, cc.VERTICAL_TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TOP);
```

and will display is ok in Firefox and Chrome, but will show the default font (Arial) on Android.

What else is to do? I checked the thread [Cocos2d-js: How to use a custom ttf font on android devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751044/cocos2d-js-how-to-use-a-custom-ttf-font-on-android-devices), but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is, that the native platforms need the full path of the ttf font, while the html platform needs the font name. I got two solutions from the cocos2d-x forum:

1. Use bitmap fonts. (Yes ... but I wanted to have ttf)
2. Code it:

In the resource file I have now:

```
var res = {
    indieflower_ttf: {type:"font", name:"IndieFlower", srcs:["res/fonts/IndieFlower.ttf"]},
}
```

Then a helper function:

```
var _b_getFontName = function(resource) {
    if (cc.sys.isNative) {
        return resource.srcs[0];
    } else {
        return resource.name;
    }
}
```

And to create a label:

```
var text = cc.LabelTTF.create("text", _b_getFontName(res.indieflower_ttf), 48, cc.size(300,0),cc.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER, cc.VERTICAL_TEXT_ALIGNMENT_TOP);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the problem as well as the solution at one place. @Michael. I can get my font to work cross platform now.

Comment: @Michael I was able to show custom ttf font on web using your method. But unfortunately it did not work on iOS. Is there any other step necessary for iOS?

Comment: @user3164248 Try to use resource.name for ios: if ( cc.sys.os == cc.sys.OS_IOS ) ... But I didn't check for it.